# Prime numbers from 10-200 using while loops only C++

Tags: c++

Hello guys here is my program to find prime numbers from 10-200, Can someone tell me whats wrong ?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void main ()
{
    int n=10 , x=2;
    bool t=false;

    while(n<=200)
    {
        while(x<n-1)
        {
            if(n%x!=0)
            {
                x++;
                t=true;
            }
        }
        if(t==true)
        {
            cout<<n <<endl;
            n++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Pretty much everything.

Comment: First thing that comes to mind - indentation. Here's a tip - if you want people to help you, you should spend some time to make your question such that it's easy to be answered.

Comment: Well , I am sorry , its my first time here and I am not familiar with loops I just took it

Comment: No joke, we could probably mark just about every line in that code as being logically incorrect for the purpose of detecting a prime, or as being logically incorrect for completing those loops.

Comment: Run through it with a pencil as though you were the computer. What are the values of `x` and `n` when you get to that first `if`? Given those values, what's going to happen? Given what happens, what effect will that have on the `while` that surrounds that test? So what will happen overall?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are so many mistakes in your code. I don't understand your logic, but you can do this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    // checking number starting from 10
    int n = 10;
    bool isPrime;

    // as long as the number is less than or equal to 200
    while(n <= 200) {

        // assume the number is prime
        isPrime = true;

        // since prime number is the number that can only be divided by 1 and itself,
        // check if this number can be divided by any number other than 1 or itself
        for (int i = 2; i < n; i++) {
            // if this number can be divided by any number other than 1 or itself,
            if (n%i == 0) {
                // then this is not a prime number, no need to check anymore
                isPrime = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (isPrime == true) {
            cout << n << endl;
        }

        // check the next number
        n++;
    }
}
```

Comment: dude , thanks alot , You are the only one who helped me here !